# How do I print term literal from rdflib in a readble way?

Tags: python, printing, sparql, dbpedia, rdflib

I just started using rdflib and I have a program that needs to get the birth date of a person (in this example, Lewis Carroll). My program does that, however when I try to print the date it prints:
(rdflib.term.Literal('1832-01-27', datatype=rdflib.term.URIRef('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date')),)

I'm sure there's an easy way to print just the date but I haven't been able to find how.
if it's of any relevance here's my code:

```
# open a graph
graph = rdflib.Graph()

# load some data
graph.parse('http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lewis_Carroll')

qres = graph.query(
    ("PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>\n"
     "PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n"
     "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\n"
     "SELECT ?birth WHERE {\n"
     "        ?person dbpedia-owl:birthDate ?birth . \n"
     "        ?person foaf:givenName ?givenName  . \n"
     "        ?person foaf:surname ?surname . \n"
     "        VALUES ?person { dbpedia:Lewis_Carroll }\n"
     "       }"
     ))

print("the graph has %s statements" % len(qres))

for row in qres:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Can you access it by something like: row[0][rdflib.term.Literal][0]? (I don't know rdflib)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to print the date from your query:

```
>>> for row in qres:
...     d = str(row.asdict()['birth'].toPython())
...     print(d)
...
1832-01-27
>>>
```

Some clues I got for solving this are rdflib.query.ResultRow.asDict() documented in http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/rdflib/query.html and rdflib.term.Literal.toPython() documented in http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apidocs/rdflib.html.

Note that row.asdict()['birth'].toPython() is a datetime.date object.

Comment: The `asdict` method is unnecessary.  You can `print row['birth'].toPython()` or `print row.birth.toPython()`.  The [docs](http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/stable/intro_to_sparql.html) say "the values can be accessed by variable name, either as attributes, or as items: row.b and row["b"] is equivalent.".